# How can I rig this 2D character so I can animate it without warping

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

So I want to rig this 2D character made of unity squares to be able to animate

[The Character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGEU3.png)

I want to rig it like this:

[Rigging idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPRef.png)

They were all made by getting cube scaling them and then arranging to make the character I was going to group upper leg to lower leg but it warps weirdly

[Warping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUfjp.png)

I don't know what to do

I tried just living with it and rotating it on the x, y or z-axis to check but all rotations are only on the z

Im clueless

Sry the images are wierd

Comment: [Animate 2D character in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXIuizGzY2A) might help you. They shows you [2D IK in Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.ik@1.1/manual/index.html) and [Character rigging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.2d.ik@1.1/manual/index.html)